# How to send a Direct message using Abraham's oauth library

Tags: php, twitter

I'm using this library ... http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

I am able to update statuses and stuff but can't seem to find a function for direct messages.

Also, is there any other library that I could use?

Answer (score 7):

Sending a direct message works almost the same as posting a status.

`$twitteroauth->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'status text here'));`

`$twitteroauth->post('direct_messages/new', array('text' => 'dm text here', 'screen_name' => 'recipients screen_name'));`