# Get all followers Email Ids in twitter in website

Tags: php, twitter

How can I get my Followers EmailID in Twitter?  I have try the following code, but it does not return emailids, it returns only Name and Screen.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<?php
$trends_url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/followers/gunarsekar.json";
////// exmaple $trends_url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/followers/w3cgallery.json"; or $trends_url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/followers/22250021.json";

$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $trends_url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$curlout = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$response = json_decode($curlout, true);
// print_r($response);
foreach($response as $friends){
 print_r($friends);
 echo "<br><br>";
$thumb = $friends['profile_image_url'];

$url = $friends['screen_name'];

$name = $friends['name'];

?>



<a title="<?php echo $name;?>" href="http://www.twitter.com/<?php echo $url;?>"><img class="photo-img" src="<?php echo $thumb?>" border="0" alt="" width="40" /></a>
<?php
} 

?>
```

Please help me to get the Email Address from Twitter.

Comment: It's possible. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235010/get-user-profile-details-especially-email-address-from-twitter-in-ios) how I achieved it in my iOS App.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Twitter API does not return a user's email address

Answer (score 4):

The Twitter API does not even provide the authenticated User's Email.........So,providing Follower's Email is out of question.......For sending Message,you should try API to send Direct Message

I use Abraham API
https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

[How to send a Direct message using Abraham's oauth library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636454/how-to-send-a-direct-message-using-abrahams-oauth-library)

Answer (score 1):

Look over this https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#6718.